# Need a SQL query for Access table with varying field names

Tags: sql, ms-access-2003

I need a SQL query to search for commas in an Access table with changing field names and show the entire record in which there is a field value with a comma. The table will always be called "Scrubbed", but the database is used to query various tables which are imported and renamed "Scrubbed". The field names will not always be the same. Here's an example of what it would look like if I knew the field names.

```
SELECT *
FROM Scrubbed
WHERE (((Scrubbed.FirstName) Like '*,*')) OR (((Scrubbed.LastName) Like '*,*'));
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions

Comment: Then you need a different query each time.  You would need to write the query using VBA, then execute it.  There is no single/generic query that could do this for you.